# Idiomatic (functional) file processing pipeline in Scala

Tags: scala

I would like to obtain an elegant pipeline for converting a textual input into a json output. The flow should go something like this:

```
(input file)              // concatenated htmls and url
Collection[String]        // unit: line
Collection[String,String] // unit: url, html doc
Collection[MyObj]         // unit: parsed MyObj
(output file)             // json representation of parsed objects
```

Currently I do this with nested for loops, but I would like to write this in a more functional style. Is there a standard way of doing this, or typical libraries I should have a look at? Note: the data is fairly large, so I can't have it entirely in memory.

Comment: I guess `Collection[MyObj] ` should be printed as JSON array? Do you have an existing solution for that?

Comment: @stholzm yes exactly. I have a function for computing the JSON of a single `MyObj`, but then I wrap it in `[,]` in the for loops.

Comment: sounds like you are looking for a library that represents the contents of a JSON array as `Iterable` or otherwise lazily. Everything else sounds doable, but I'm out of ideas there. Someone got an idea?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use Scalaz-stream. The library provides compositionality, expressiveness, resource safety, and speed to process IO. Also, It uses instant memory which will be very useful for handling large data. Here is github for that:

https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream

Youtube talk about it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSZhUZT7Fyc

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCxBEUyIBt0

Comment: That does look very interesting... Also linked from that page: [Machines](https://github.com/ekmett/machines/)

Comment: "Streaming parsing" is still on the roadmap though. Not sure how to do the the JSON part of the question.

Comment: I use this library in my project, it looks awesome when handling huge data and process it in parallel. I don't think it is hard to integrate it with JSON library like argonaut (http://argonaut.io/). It can serialize and deserialize it in a handy way.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use for comprehensions for such tasks with *scala-arm* for resource management (`AutoClosable`, `Closeable` etc).

Many scala tutorials use `for { s <- Source.fromFile(...).getLines() }` but it's a good way to resource leak, since Source won't be closed automagically.

With *scala-arm* it looks like:

```
import resource._

for { source <- managed(Source.fromFile(...))
      target <- managed(Files.newBufferedWriter(...)) } {
  for { rawLine <- source.getLines
        line = rawLine.trim() if !rawLine.startsWith("#")
        (url, html) <- parseString(line)
        json <- toJsonOpt(html) } {
    // actual action
    target.write(s"$url\t$json\n")
  }
}
```

If you need more complicated pipeline, you can use *scalaz-stream*, *strom*, *spark* or some other library for defining actual pipeline DAG and start its execution.